# Does Threadsy auto-refresh?

Tags: email

I just signed up to Threadsy. But I'm not quite sure if it auto-refreshes to look for new emails, tweets or Facebook status updates. I told my sister to send me a message so I can check if it does work, and continued reading my feeds on Google Reader, just like I normally do. After two minutes, Threadsy still didn't know I had a new email. Then I clicked on the tab where I had Threadsy open, and went back to GReader right away. Then, seconds later, it told me  I had a new email.

Is it because it auto-refreshes after more than two minutes, or because I actually went on the site and then it checked?

Answer (score 1):

From their help file:

**how frequently does threadsy check for new messages?**

threadsy checks frequently when you're signed in and less frequently when you're not. you can also do a manual refresh by clicking on the 'inbound' link.

I also read on the 'net that there's a built in 10 minute cache.

Answer (score 0):

The refresh rate is much higher than 10 minutes. I've been a long time user and I can send myself e-mails and see them easily within 5 minutes. The "Streams" refresh rate seems event faster, to keep up with the Twitter/Facebook activity. Oddly enough they still don't have an "offical" rate mentioned anywhere in their FAQ or GetSatisfaction page, but maybe that is just a "mystery" they leave out there. 8^D